# How to use this.state in my filter function when render component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code...

```
   somarray.user.filter(function(ele, index) {
       if(this.state.showAllUser == false) {
        return (index < 3)
       }
       else {
        return true
       }
  })
```

When I render my component, the 'this.state.showAllUser' inside this filter function is undefined.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Here are some relevant questions: (1) What is the context in which this code appears? (2) Where/how is the component state set? (3) Is `this.state.showUser` undefined, or is `this.state` undefined?

Comment: 'this.state' seems likes is windows object not the thing which I set in getInitialState function.

Comment: That means you need to bind the scope of `this` on the function passed to `filter`. Assuming that `this` refers to your component instance in the scope where you call `somearray.user.filter`, try: `somearray.user.filter(function(e,i){...}.bind(this))`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is some documentation on `this`, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is some documentation on `Function.prototype.bind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this isn't defined correctly in the function. Fix it by binding it so that it has the correct definition.

```
 somarray.user.filter(function(ele, index) {
       if(this.state.showAllUser == false) {
        return (index < 3)
       }
       else {
        return true
       }
  }.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just figure out by myself but still appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

You can also store ´this´ in another variable like so:

```
var self = this
somarray.user.filter(function(ele, index) {
   if(self.state.showAllUser == false) {
    return (index < 3)
   }
   else {
    return true
   }
})
```

This way ´self.state.showAllUser´ will have the value you expect